# Xcode changes storyboard xml automatically

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, storyboard

I recently upgraded the Xcode to 6.3.2.
After editing the storyboard, i noticed some strange changes through git:
All the

`cocoaTouchSystemColor="colour"/>`

nodes have been changed to

```
red="value" green="value" blue="value" alpha="value" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
```

in the xml file of the storyboard (I have not made those changes for sure).

for example:

```
cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>

                ||
                ||
                \/

red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
```

Does anyone know where this comes from? I guess that this is a new behaviour from the new Xcode version, but its only a gues.
Furthermore, are those two values 100% identical? so is for example behind the constant "darkTextColour" the RGB value of 0,0,0?

Thank you.

Comment: A quick inspection at a playground seems to verify that `darkTextColour` is indeed a black with 1.0 alpha (w 0.0 a 1.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode has a long history of changing storyboard files on its own. It does the same thing with xib files. It comes from Xcode, by design, and there's nothing that people outside of Apple can do except deal with it. File a bug with Apple. If you like, roll back this change via git or whatever source-control tool you use.

Answer (score 1):

These are optimizations Xcode does automatically when the storyboard XML format changes. You can also see that the version numbers at the top of the XML have been updated.

And yes, `darkTextColor` has always been complete black, so this is still the same color.